# Hiding columns by client Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just wondering if there are any ways to hide columns (client-side) for different users accessing the sheet?

I know you can create filter views that allows users to view and edit without having to change the actual orientation of the sheet, but I can't seem to find any way to hide columns while creating a filter view.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do your spreadsheet user will require editing access to columns that visible to them? Will users having different visible columns could access the spreadsheet at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

One solution perhaps to your problem is to structure your data across several spreadsheet documents and give access to different people to each sheet.

Let's say you have a have a master spreadsheet containing all the data as a single source of truth. Then you can use an import formula in a different spreadsheet document to display certain data from the master spreadsheet.

The slave documents can be projected as need and will update automatically when the master spreadsheet is changed. Below are some formulas that can do this

Generic import data formula

```
 =IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url,Sheet1A:A")
```

Import formula to import only display certain - need to project the whole sheet from being copied etc.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","Sheet1!A1:C"),"SELECT Col1, Col3",0)
```